# Wait for callback response in AngularJS / Ionic

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ionic-framework, callback

Is it possible to wait for a callback response before return the result?
I'm using ionic with AngularJS.

Comment: Yep its possible. :P

Comment: This is stupid, but what flag do I use?

Answer (score 3):

yes you can. for example `one` is a callback function which wait until that function is finish executing and only then it start executing function `two`

```js
function two() {
 console.log("value is two")
}
function one(callback) {
 console.log("value is one")
 callback()
}
one(function() {
 two()
})
```